What is the criteria of forming a phonon polariton?
It is well know that, phonon polariton is a quasiparticle formed by the interaction between photons and optical phonons. But, does it mean that, any photons that are resonant with phonons can form polaritons? What are the criteria?

Textbooks draw curves of it throughout slices in the Brillouin zone. You should just read up about the topic.

Their wavevectors $k$ and energies $E$ must be similar to each other, while obeying the anticrossing principle
